# Tkinter - Calling a function with arguments, after a button gets pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

In a function, I create multiply buttons with this line of code (`buttons` is a list).

```
self.buttons.append(Button(self.parent, text="Browse", command=testFunction????))
....

def testFunction(self, number):
....
```

When a button gets pressed, it should call the `testFunction` with a specific Number (button 1: 1, button 2: 2 and so on). 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lambda to pass the arguments:

```
self.buttons.append(Button(self.parent, 
                           text="Browse", 
                           command=lambda number=num: self.testFunction(number)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda

```
self.buttons.append(Button(self.parent,text="Browse",command=lambda num = number: self.testFunction(num)))
....
def testFunction(self, number):
...
```

If this doesn't work, then create a button(use lambda as well) and then append it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!